# Export .env file in npm script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to make some test in my react app and i need to export my .env file.
I can't use dotenv because it can't be minified in react.

I want to add my .env file in my test script. Something like:

test: 'export .env mocha...."

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without using any additional libraries, is to create a JS file that exports an object with typical Node ENVs as properties. Then import this file and set variables based upon the current process.env.NODE_ENV. **The obvious drawback is that you have an accessible file stored on disk that may contain sensitive data**.

For example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/qq0vwrn1zq

**env/config.js**

```
export default {
  "development": {
    name: "Bob"
  },
  "production": {
    name: "Jim"
  },
  "staging": {
    name: "Alexa"
  },
  "test": {
    name: "Nancy"
  }
};
```

**example.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import config from "./env/config";
import "./styles.css";

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const name = config[env].name;
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Current ENV: {env}</h1>
      <h2>Current Name: {name}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), you can do it like this.

```
node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```

If you don't specify the path for .env file, it will read from the project root.

Comment: so, if i'm using mocha how can i do it? i have to make the mocha script in a js file and execute it?

Comment: @SaitoHs simply replace 'node' in the example script with 'mocha'.